# R: sum of number of rows of one data based on row-specific dynamic conditions from another data

Tags: r, dynamic, sum, minimum, rowwise

Consider the following data:

```
Country1 = c("Brazil", "India", "China","China","Brazil")
Date1<-as.Date(c("2001-01-21", "2002-04-13","2003-06-19","2006-06-19","2007-06-19"))
Name1<-c("B","C","A","A","A")
Data1<-data.frame(Country1,Date1,Name1)

Name2<-c("B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A")
Quality2<-c("good","good","medium","good","good","bad","good","good")
Country2<-c("China","Brazil","Taiwan","India","India","United States","China","Brazil")
Date2<-as.Date(c("2002-02-21", "1999-03-13","1998-08-19", "1996-09-13","2000-12-12","1998-07-21","2005-03-22","2003-06-19"))
Data2<-data.frame(Name2,Quality2,Country2,Date2)
```

In Data1, I want to add a column by the name of "Result". The "Result" (for each row of Data1) should be the sum of number of rows of Data2 which meet four conditions (1) Data2$Name2 should match row’s entry of Data1$Name1, (2) Data2$Country2 should match row’s entry of Data1$Country1, (3) Data2$Quality2 should be “good”, (4) Data2$Date2 should be less than row’s entry of Data1$Date1. So, Data1$Result should be 1, 2, 0, 1, and 1.

For example, for the first row, Data1$Result should be 1 because Data2 has only 1 row that meets these conditions:
`sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[1] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[1] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[1])`

Or, in other words

`sum(Data2$Name2=="B" & Data2$Country2=="Brazil" & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < "2001-01-21")`

In the same way, for the second row, Data1$Result should be 2 because Data2 has 2 row that meet these conditions: `sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[2] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[2] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[2])`

Or,

`sum(Data2$Name2=="C" & Data2$Country2=="India" & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < "2002-04-13")`.

For the third row, Data1$Result should be 0 because Data2 does not have any row that meets these conditions: 
`sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[3] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[3] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[3])`

Alternatively,

`sum(Data2$Name2=="A" & Data2$Country2=="China" & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < "2003-06-19")`.

Same goes for 4th and 5th rows:

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[4] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[4] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[4])

sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[5] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[5] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[5])
```

As a beginner in R, I wrote the following code:

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[1:nrow(Data1)] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[1:nrow(Data1)] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[1:nrow(Data1)])
```

However, it does not return the desired outcome. I want to write a dynamic code based on row number of Data1. In my actual data, I have around 100,000 observations in each data.

Ideally, I am looking for some code that R reads depending on row number of Data1 “n”.

For example, for 1st row, R should execute

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[1] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[1] & ata2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[1])
```

For second row,

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[2] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[2] & ata2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[2])
```

For (lets say) 54,342th row

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[54342] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[54342] & ata2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[54342])
```

For nth row

```
sum(Data2$Name2==as.character(Data1$Name1)[n] & Data2$Country2==as.character(Data1$Country1)[n] & Data2$Quality2=="good" & Data2$Date2 < Data1$Date1[n])
```

Also, I want to add another column in Data1 by the name of “Min.Date.Result” which gives me the smallest (oldest) value of Data2$Date2 which meets the same four conditions. So Data1$Min.Date.Result should be “1999-03-13”, “1996-09-13”,“NA”, "2005-03-22", "2003-06-19".

Answer (score 0):

We can `filter` the `Quality2` to keep `"Good"` rows, join it with `Data1`, `group_by` `Country2` and count number of rows where `Date2 < Date1` and the minimum value.

```
library(dplyr)

Data2 %>%
  filter(Quality2 == 'good') %>%
  right_join(Data1, by = c('Name2' = 'Name1', 'Country2' = 'Country1')) %>%
  group_by(Country2) %>%
  summarise(Result = sum(Date2 < Date1), 
            Date1 = min(Date2[Date2 < Date1]))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Country2 Result Date1     
#  <chr>     <int> <date>    
#1 Brazil        1 1999-03-13
#2 China         0 NA        
#3 India         2 1996-09-13
```

---

For the updated data, we can change the approach and do :

```
Data1 %>%
  left_join(Data2, by = c('Name1' = 'Name2', 'Country1' = 'Country2')) %>%
  group_by(Country1, Date1) %>%
  summarise(Result = sum(Date2 < Date1 & Quality2 == "good"), 
            Date = min(Date2[Date2 < Date1 & Quality2 == "good"]))

#  Country1 Date1      Result Date      
#  <chr>    <date>      <int> <date>    
#1 Brazil   2001-01-21      1 1999-03-13
#2 China    2003-06-19      0 NA        
#3 China    2006-06-19      1 2005-03-22
#4 India    2002-04-13      2 1996-09-13
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. However, In Data 1, there could multiple observations with same "Name1". In that case, I am not sure how we will add the Result column based on the output from your code.
Edit: I have added a 4th row in Data1 in the main post.

Comment: Sorry that I keep on editing data to make case more complex. In the actual data, there are multiple categories of Data1$Name1, which have the same Data1$Country1. In the edited post, I have added a 5th row for which Country1=="Brazil". As mentioned, the actual data is in thousands. So there are many cases where entries Date1, Country1, or Name1 are repeated. So any entry in Country1 or Date1 is not specific to particular entry in Name1. 5th row in Data1 is an example of this (where Brazil is a repeated entry).

Comment: The second question remains the same. How can we add Data1$Result and Data1$Min.Date.Result from the output of your code?Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Comment: @KashifAhmed It is not exactly clear to me how this edit differs in the application of the answer. Did you try the answer? What did it return? Probably, you want to add another group `Name1` in `group_by` ? As far as second question is concerned it is already present in the answer, you need to assign the data back like `Data3 <- Data1 %>%
  left_join(Data2, by = .......rest of the answer`, the `Min.Date.Result` is called `Date` in my answer. Check `Data3`.